# Erro em INNER JOIN Mysql e exibição em JSON

Tags: php, mysql

Olá

Eu preciso exibir os resultados de um SELECT com INNER JOIN em formato JSON, minha query esta funcionando, pois testei dentro do PHPMYADMIN, mas na minha pagina não funciona, já testei de tudo, oque pode ser ? Alguem me ajuda a achar o erro ? Deve ser algo muito simples.

Meu SQL

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
    -- version 4.6.4
    -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
    --
    -- Host: 127.0.0.1
    -- Generation Time: May 30, 2017 at 01:45 PM
    -- Server version: 5.7.14
    -- PHP Version: 5.6.25

    SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
    SET time_zone = "+00:00";


    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

    --
    -- Database: `projeto001`
    --

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `compras`
    --

    CREATE TABLE `compras` (
      `id` int(100) NOT NULL,
      `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `projeto` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `produto` varchar(100) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `compras`
    --

    INSERT INTO `compras` (`id`, `username`, `projeto`, `produto`) VALUES
    (1, 'Fulano', 'Projeto Novo', 'produto01');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `empresa`
    --

    CREATE TABLE `empresa` (
      `id` int(100) NOT NULL,
      `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `projeto` varchar(100) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `empresa`
    --

    INSERT INTO `empresa` (`id`, `username`, `projeto`) VALUES
    (1, 'Fulano', 'Projeto Novo');

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `estoque`
    --

    CREATE TABLE `estoque` (
      `id` int(100) NOT NULL,
      `produto` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `quantidade` varchar(100) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `estoque`
    --

    INSERT INTO `estoque` (`id`, `produto`, `quantidade`) VALUES
    (1, 'produto01', '100');

    --
    -- Indexes for dumped tables
    --

    --
    -- Indexes for table `compras`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `compras`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

    --
    -- Indexes for table `empresa`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `empresa`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

    --
    -- Indexes for table `estoque`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `estoque`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
    --

    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `compras`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `compras`
      MODIFY `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `empresa`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `empresa`
      MODIFY `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `estoque`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `estoque`
      MODIFY `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Meu Código

```
    <?php

    $projeto = $_GET['projeto'];

    //PDO is a extension which defines a lightweight, consistent interface for accessing databases in PHP.
    $db=new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydatabase;host=localhost;','username','password');
    //here prepare the query for analyzing, prepared statements use less resources and thus run faster
    $nome = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));

    //Produtos
    $row=$db->prepare("SELECT empresa.username, empresa.projeto, compras.username, compras.projeto, compras.produto, estoque.produto FROM `empresa` AS empresa LEFT JOIN `compras` AS compras ON compras.`username` = empresa.`username` AND compras.`projeto` = empresa.`projeto` LEFT JOIN `estoque` AS estoque ON compras.`produto` = estoque.`produto` WHERE empresa.projeto = 'Projeto Novo' and compras.username = 'Fulano'");

    $row->execute();//execute the query
    $json_data=array();//create the array
    foreach($row as $rec)//foreach loop
    {
    $json_array['empresa.username']=$rec['empresa.username'];
    $json_array['empresa.projeto']=$rec['empresa.projeto'];
    $json_array['compras.username']=$rec['compras.username'];
    $json_array['compras.projeto']=$rec['compras.projeto'];
    $json_array['compras.produto']=$rec['compras.produto'];
    $json_array['estoque.produto']=$rec['estoque.produto'];
    //here pushing the values in to an array
    array_push($json_data,$json_array);

    }

    //built in PHP function to encode the data in to JSON format
    echo json_encode($json_data);
    ?>
```

Valew

Comment: Qua erro você obtém?

Comment: Dizer que não está funcionando é muito abrangente. Qual é o erro/resultado que está obtendo e qual era o esperado?

Comment: então o problema é que nada é exibido na tela, teria que exibir o resultado com uma formatação JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente este código, fiz uma alteração, adicionei a variável $linhas e o fetchall.

```
<?php

//Produtos
$row=$db->prepare("SELECT empresa.username, empresa.projeto, compras.username, compras.projeto, compras.produto, estoque.produto FROM `empresa` AS empresa LEFT JOIN `compras` AS compras ON compras.`username` = empresa.`username` AND compras.`projeto` = empresa.`projeto` LEFT JOIN `estoque` AS estoque ON compras.`produto` = estoque.`produto` WHERE empresa.projeto = 'Projeto Novo' and compras.username = 'Fulano'");

$row->execute();
$json_data=array();
$results = $row->fetchAll();

foreach($results as $rec)
{
    $json_array['username']=$rec['username'];
    $json_array['projeto']=$rec['projeto'];
    $json_array['produto']=$rec['produto'];

    //here pushing the values in to an array
    array_push($json_data,$json_array);
}

//built in PHP function to encode the data in to JSON format
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Comment: Eu testei o código, mas não funcionou, o problema é que o array esta vindo vazio, será que o problema esta no SELECT, talvez as aspas simples ?

Comment: abduzeedo, tem como colar o SQL da sua base, vou replicar e consigo resolver. Uma dúvida, quando você cola o SQL que está aí acima direto no banco e executa, volta algum resultado?

Comment: Editei o código e inseri o meu SQL para criar o Banco de Dados, creio que assim fica mais fácil para me ajudar. Obrigado

Comment: Olá Bruno. Tudo Bem ? Qual será o erro ?

Comment: Atualizado o código, fiz o import da sua base e corrigi o código, agora está funcional.

Comment: Obs, retirei a string de conexão. O mais importante ali que estava faltando é "$results = $row->fetchAll();", sem essa linha, você estava tentando ler o conteúdo da string da consulta e não no objeto retornado da consulta. Também as colunas do array retornado estavam incorretas. O nome da coluna não é acompanhado pelo nome da tabela, a não ser que coloque um alias para cada coluna com os nomes que estavam anteriormente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59569/discussion-between-abduzeedo-and-bruno-rigolon).

Answer (score 0):

Olá, coloque antes do json_encode o seguinte código:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Isto serve para que a resposta seja no formato json, sem isto, sua resposta é considerada uma página web.

Obs.: Você não pode ter nenhuma saída de conteúdo antes de setar o header, caso já tenha dado saída em algum conteúdo, receberá uma mensagem de aviso/erro do php.

Comment: Então, meu código esta funcionando, pois já testei com um SELECT simples, mas agora nada aparece utilizando o SELECT com INNER JOIN, talvez o erro esteja na hora de exibir os dados na tela.

Comment: É provável que esteja recebendo algum erro do PHP. Adicione estas linhas no início do código para exibi-los:

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Com isto, conseguiremos ter uma ideia melhor do erro que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Não deu erro nenhum.

Comment: de um var_dump($json_data) e diga o que retorna.